# Java: how to connect to different servers from a client socket on one port?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, port

A TCP connection is identified by four elements(maybe protocol included): client port, client address, server port, server address. So it's possible for a client with one port to connect to multiple different servers.Because they're different TCP connections.

Here's my demo: a local client on port 9999 conncecting to two local servers on port 12345 and port 12346. But the code isn't correct.

Can anybody help me? Tell me how to correct it, please.(not use SO_REUSEPORT or fork)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SocketTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        startServer(12345);
        startServer(12346);

        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
        System.out.println("client: " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());

        startClient(socket, 12345);
        startClient(socket, 12346);
    }

    public static void startClient(Socket socket, int port) {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Problem: connect() can be called only once
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(port));
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void startServer(int port) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ServerSocket ss;
                try {
                    ss = new ServerSocket(port);
                    System.out.println("listen on: " + ss.getLocalSocketAddress());
                    while (true) {
                        Socket s = ss.accept();
                        System.out.println("accept from: " + s.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What do you care what local port the client uses? 'the code isn't correct' is not a problem report. Why isn't SO_REUSEADDR acceptable? Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to make a demo to verify my thought: it's possible to connect to 2 different servers using a socket on one port. However my code doesn't work as what i wish. Can you give me a revision to the code?

Comment: Are you trying to do multicasting?

Comment: @SergeBallesta no, just bidirectional communication^_^

Comment: @EJP Soooo sorry!  I don't care about what local port the client uses. Just try to make multiple connections from a socket to different servers, maybe impracticable. The problem is I don't know how to achieve it if it's possible and  i want to know if any other way exists besides SO_REUSEADDR.

Comment: You **can't** make multiple connections from a single socket. You can do so from a single *port*, but only *if* the kernel lets you, and if you have a requirement to do so. The way to achieve multiple connections to a server is to forget about the local port. Don't bind the socket, and don't mention its local address or port when constructing or connecting it. You still haven't stated an actual problem, and you still haven't confided in us what your unnatural aversion so SO_REUSEADDR is. Not that it's relevant. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: @EJP I misunderstood sth before. Now from server perspective, server's accept() receives client connections and then create(return) a new socket for each connection. These new created sockets generated by system are all bind to the same port. Conversely, for client, there alo should be multiple sockets binding to the same port. That sockets sharing the same port on server side is done naturally and easily achieved, but one client side it's difficult to realize(no function can return a new socket using the same port other sockets binding to).

Comment: @EJP  As for SO_REUSEADDR, it's used in TIME_WAIT period and most commonly used on server side. What I expect is to create multiple client sockets under the same port to connect to different server at the same time, not in sequency. SO_REUSEPORT can make it, but SO_REUSEPORT is not fully supported on all platform(maybe i'm wrong).  A derivative is the question that "how many TCP connections to servers  at most can a client hold theoretically". Less than 65535 or more than 65535(up to 2^64)?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind 2 different sockets to the same local port (that is what SO_REUSEADDR is made for), but one single socket can only be connected to one single destination.

If you want to send one single message, and you want that message to be received by two servers, then you need multicast. multicast can only use UDP (not TCP)  and one of the special multicast addresses  (224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255) that isn't listed as [reserved](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml) by IANA.

Comment: why "one single socket can only be connected to one single destination"？One connection comprises socket (192.168.1.101:9999) and destination one(192.168.1.101:12345); another  connection comprises socket (192.168.1.101:9999) and destination one(192.168.1.101:12346). Two connections are distinct. Given one single socket can be connected to multiple destinations, the single socket can tell these connections, send different messages to the servers, receive the messages the servers send and there is no problem. Why can a socket connect to one destination only? Why this limit exsits?

Comment: @Qoobee: you are making a confusion between an address (IP+port) and a socket. The socket is the handle that allows you to manipulate an *exchange* between two addresses. A TCP connection is a long living connection between two addresses (src and dst IP+port) that you manipulate through a socket. Why is it like that? Because it is the way it was implemented in BSD4...